# conditional php using a form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am trying to create a page that the user fills out and then stores the values of the form and on the same page, only displays the text "Hi firstname lastname" with their name that they entered on the form displayed on the screen. I am getting a server error (500) when I try to do this.

```
<html>
<title>PHP Example</title>
<script>
    function validation() {
        var x = document.forms["submit"]["firstname"].value;
        var y = document.forms["submit"]["lastname"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "" || y == null || y == "") {
            alert("Error");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>

</html>

<?php
     if (isset($_REQUEST["firstname"]) == false) { ?>
    <form name="submit" action="test5.php" method="get" onsubmit="return validation()">
        <p>First name:
            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Jane" />
        </p>
        <p>Last name:
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Doe" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <?php 
    } 
    else if (isset($_REQUEST["firstname"] == true) { 
      echo $_POST['firstname'] . $_POST['lastname'];
      echo "Hi " . $_REQUEST['firstname'] . " " . $_REQUEST['lastname'] . "!";
    } ?>

</html>
```

Comment: Second `isset` missing a parenthesis (where you are checking for true)

Comment: @Qirel  Ah, silly mistake. Thanks! That fixed it.

Comment: Take a look at [`error_reporting(-1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). Would've let you know what was wrong too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Missing parenthesis, change

```
else if (isset($_REQUEST["firstname"] == true) {
```

to

```
else if (isset($_REQUEST["firstname"]) == true) {
```

Comment: It's a simple typo, which that makes it an "off-topic" question - [staying on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)